# Custom Fields - List Posts on Map

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps, custom-post-type

I have created custom fields using Types plugin, and beside standard fields (text, photo...) i have 2 "map related" fields - longitude and latitude (which i am adding in this format - 40.712784) and those 2 fields get outputed as raw code on the page using this code:

```
 <?php echo(types_render_field( "long", array( 'raw' => true) )); ?>
 <?php echo(types_render_field( "lat", array( 'raw' => true) )); ?>
```

Now, i would want to display marker for each post on a Google Map on top of my homepage by its long/lat location, but since i am not a PHP developer, i dont have any idea where to start.

Of course, i know this isnt just a 5 min job, but any idea where and how to start would be good.

Thank you!

Comment: Quick question, do you need to only output the 1 pin at a time? Or will you have a group of pins being put on 1 map?

Comment: @maxinacube Ideally, if the user came from, lets say, Germany, map would zoom in and only show pins from that area.
But that is way out of my league, so for now, i would wish to show all of them at 1 map